# Why the two const int objects have same address but not same value after "const" cast?

Tags: c++, pointers, int, constants

Please see, I defined `const int & a = 1` by reference, and forced the pointer to convert `pa` to `a`, and changed the value of a by changing `pa`. This was successful.

But when `const int k = 1` is defined and the above operation is repeated, although `pk` and `k` are the same address, `* pk` and `k` are not the same value.

What is the principle behind it?

Could you please explain how the IDE work with the memory allocation when I do so?

```
const int &a = 1;
    int *pa = (int*)&a;
    cout << &a << endl;
    cout << pa << endl;
    *pa = 2;
    cout << a << endl;
//And here is the outcome.


//0x7ffeeb5d8a24
//0x7ffeeb5d8a24
//2
```

So here we changed `a` successfully.

```
    const int k = 1;
    cout << &k << endl;
    int *pk = (int*)&k;
    cout << &k << endl;
    cout << pk << endl;
    *pk = 2;
    cout << *pk << ' ' << k;

//0x7ffeeb5d8a14
//0x7ffeeb5d8a14
//0x7ffeeb5d8a14
//2 1
//Process finished with exit code 0
```

`*pk`and`k`here have same address, but not the same value! 
How could this happen?

Comment: You're only allowed to modify `const_cast`ed objects if they originally weren't const. `const int &a = 1;` is a const reference to a non-const temporary `int`, so you're allowed to modify it after casting away constness. But `const int k = 1;` is an actual `const` object, so you're not allowed to modify it in any way.

Comment: The value of `k` can be generated directly into the instruction stream as an immediate mode constant, without requiring a load.

Answer (score 5):

This is technically *undefined behavior*.  It is not safe to modify `const` data at runtime, even if you cast away its const-ness.  Only data that is initially non-`const` and has `const` added to it later can safely have that `const` casted away.

But, to explain why you are seeing the output that is confusing you - the answer is *compiler optimization*!

The compiler sees `const int k = 1;` as a **compile-time constant** and assumes `k` will never change value (and rightly so!).  When the compiler sees `cout << *pk << ' ' << k;`, it is allowed to replace `k` with the value `1` right there at the call site *at compile-time*, thus you are really executing `cout << *pk << ' ' << 1;` regardless of what you do to `k` *at runtime*.  But, being that `k` is a compile-time constant that you take the address of, it has to be stored in memory, and the compiler is free to (and likely will) store that value in read-only memory.  Altering such memory at runtime is likely to crash your app, but that is not a *guarantee*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  But may I ask you to explain that If the compiler replaced ```k```with ```1```, then could assume that  ```1``` and the ```2``` as numbers shared the same address, according to the output of address data ? hence this is kind of a paradox, isn't it? ( I tried to think over according to your answer)

Comment: "*then could assume that `1` and the `2` as numbers shared the same address*" - if the compiler replaces `k` with `1` at the call site, the `1` is used literally in the function call, eg `cout << 1` is `cout.operator<<(1)` where `1` exists as a literal on the call stack only for the duration of the function call, there is no memory allocated for it. Look at the machine code that your compiler generates, you will see something like this: `PUSH 1; LEA EAX, cin; PUSH EAX; CALL istream::operator<<;` rather than `MOV EAX, [k]; PUSH EAX; LEA EAX, cin; PUSH EAX; CALL istream::operator<<;`

Comment: Thank you for you patient answer! It's very horrible to learn the basic level of C++ too much. So complex!  I think it's done !